# Mysql: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE: Only update when value has changed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table where I use this query:

```
INSERT INTO `stats` (`id`, `shop`, `price`, `timestamp`)
VALUES (NULL, '$shop', '$price', 'timestamp') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price='$price'
```

The shop column is unique. "Id" = primary key. The timestamp column is updated by mysql: on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
Data in the dB:

row: id=1, shop=viacom, price=5, timestamp=1524183480
```

**Case 1:** Row to be inserted: shop=viacom, price=6
**Result:** The existing row is updated

**Case 2:**  Row to be inserted: shop=viacom, price=5 (<-- price has NOT changed)
 **Result:** The existing row is **NOT** updated

I would like to get case 2 working. I can handle it with php-code, but I'd rather let Mysql do that job. Any ideas? (I tried adding a Where Clause like $shop=shop)

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking, especially regarding the second case. Please show proper example data for what you’d want to insert/update/ignore when exactly.

Comment: Ok, added an example.

Comment: If you update same values, How do you know that is doesn't work ?

Comment: Good point, I have a timestamp column as well, I edited the question with that info.

Comment: Why you try to insert 4 values into 3 columns ?

Comment: Forgot to add the column in this question: fixed.

Comment: Can you add table schema ?

Comment: @DaveyD did you find a solution for this without using PHP to check if the price has changed?

Comment: I really can't remember, this is a question that I posted 4.5 years ago ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the `timestamp` column manually:

```
INSERT INTO `stats` (`shop`, `price`) VALUES ('$shop', '$price')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price='$price', timestamp = NOW();
```

=========

Option #2:

If you want to do it in MySQL, create stored procedure and call the stored procedure from PHP code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `createOrUpdatePrice` (ex_shop varchar(255),ex_price int(11))
BEGIN
declare occures tinyint(1);
SELECT COUNT(`shop`) into occures from `stats` WHERE shop = ex_shop;
IF occures = 0 Then
INSERT INTO `stats` (`id`, `shop`, `price`) VALUES (NULL, ex_shop, ex_price);
ELSE
UPDATE `stats` SET price = ex_price where shop = ex_shop;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Your answer does the same as my current query, it won't work in case 2.

Comment: Update table schema in your question. `SHOW CREATE TABLE stats;`

Answer (score -1):

Since the shop column is a UNIQUE key, you can remove the id column and use the below.

```
replace into stats (shop, price) values ('$shop', '$price')
```

If shop already exists, then the price is updated. Else a new shop will be inserted. Is this what you want?

Comment: Id = primary key, so should be unique too. I don't want a new shop to be inserted, but only an update for the price column when the price has changed.